# Unable to access uploaded file from a sub-domain of the website

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

I created a sub-domain for my website that acts as a file depot for it. It contains all the configurations and images etc. I uploaded a file to the server and done following settings:

- Allowed Write Permissions
- Allowed Directory Browsing
- Allowed Parent Paths
- Set read permission to this file and its parent folders for all users
- Allowed Anonymous Access
- Enabled Basic and Windows Authentication

But I am getting following error when I try to enter the link of that file like subdomain.mywebsite.com/setup/sd.txt

It shows following error:

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Note that directory browsing is working properly when I go to the folder of this file. But the file is not accessible directly.

I am not good at configuring servers. So any one can please tell me why this is happening and what is the solution?

Comment: 404, means you probably have your filepath wrong in your code.